# How to make a SPAN have no background

Tags: css

I have the following HTML code:

```
<div id="bg">
    <span id="topnav">
    About Us | Contact Us | Media Room | Events | Career Opportunities
    </span>
    <input type=text size=25 id=insidebgtext />
</div>
```

The CSS code:

```
#bg {
    position: absolute;
    background: url('bg.png');
    height: 50px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1;
}
#insidebgtext {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25%;
    right: 20%;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    z-index: 2;
}
#topnav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
    left: 20%;
    z-index: 5;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Verdana, Tahoma;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```

I didn't set a background for the span but why is the span inheriting the page's red background color and not have any background at all?

Comment: as `#bg` is the parent `#topnav`, thats why its having the `bg.png` background.

Comment: #bg is actually the tranparent ribbon and not the background

Comment: What is red? Your body?

Comment: can you give the full url of the background in the #bg, so we can run some fiddle.

Comment: Yes Red is the color of the body's background color. And I added another span and it's also taking the background color of the page instead of the #bg ribbon

Comment: @rockStar Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acg4g/ You see how the span inherit's the body's background color?

Comment: just remove this `background-color: #CCCCCC;` as you declared it as a global background. And if you want a `#CCCCCC` background within the contents of your site just add the `background-color` to that certain div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bg` is the parent of your `span`. So if you provide the background to the parent `bg` and not giving any background to `child` then child is automatically uses the background-color of parent.

If you don't want to use the same background for `span` you need to give the other color. `Background :none`  will not work in this case.

You can understand it like this. Assuming there is layer of parent which is having `background:red` and the child is place over it and having no background, in that case background of child will automatically red.

So you have to put a `background-color` of child which looks like it has no background like this

```
#topnav {
  background:#FFF
}
```

**[JS Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/PT4xA/)**

Comment: the parent is BG which is the ribbon at top and from what you are saying the SPAN isn't inheriting the background instead it is displaying the entire page's background color, which is red

Comment: `topNav` should not have any background color is what I want :/

Comment: It's background should be the same as the ribbon's background. If you remove the `background-color: #fff` from the topnav from yor jsfiddle, you see how it's background is blending in with the page background? That's not happening to my topnav. There is the ribbon in between the topnav and the page so shouldn't it inherit the ribbon's bg?

Comment: Here is the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acg4g/ You see how the span inherit's the body's background color?

Comment: it is because of you put background-color with `*` selector. remove it from there and give to the `body`. see the updated http://jsfiddle.net/acg4g/1/

Answer (score 1):

Do not give it a background in first place :)

```
* {
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}
```

Think it twice before using a global selector and **do not forget about it**

Not an answer, just a reminder :)

Answer (score 0):

It is because child elements inherit the properties of their parent element.

If you want to remove it, then you need to reset the `background` property of that element yourself.

```
span { #topnav would be in the place of span
   /* here */
}
```

The background of the parent (#bg) is being applied:

```
background: url('bg.png'); // this line from #bg
```

Comment: The SPAN is not inheriting the background because the #bg is for the ribbon on top and not the background for the page itself.